# C# analysis fails without .pdb files

Tags: c#, fxcop, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying out the new C# plugin v3.0 with SonarQube 4.2.
According to plugin documentation, I need .pdb files to run analysis which includes FxCop rules, and indeed I get a failure message when executing sonar-runner if said .pdb files are not present in the output folder; FxCop exits with code 1536.

The thing is, the analysis seems to require .pdb files for ALL the binnaries, and the output folder contains several dependencies in addition to my own compiled code. These are NuGet packages and I cannot find symbol files for all of them.

So, is there any way I can have the analysis to skip the files without debugging symbols?
The regular SonarQube file exclusion lists seem to apply to source code files only (e.g. *.designer.cs) and not for binnaries.

Comment: What is your configuration? It looks like you can explicitly indicate dlls you would like to analyze with FxCop: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/csharp/sonar-project-without-visual-studio-bootstrapper.properties

Comment: Tried that, the example in the link, tried configurations with and without the bootstrapper, but no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug on the SonarQube C# plugin side. I have created the following ticket to fix it: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARFXCOP-29

Note that this is not related to the presence of *.pdb files, but only on the presence of the referenced assemblies.